# Unable to capture next line character in Java

Tags: java, regex, contains

I have a requirement of parsing through an python file which contains multiple sql queries and get the start and end positions of the query to get only the query part using JAVA

I am using .contains function to check for **`sql('''`** as my opening character for the query and now for the closing character I have **`''')`** but there are some cases where `''')` comes in between the query when there is a variable involved which should not be detected as an end of the query.

Something like this :

```
spark.sql(''' SELECT .......
FROM..... 
WHERE  xxx IN ('''+ Variable +''')
''')
```

here the last but one line also gets detected as end of line if I use `line.contains(" ''') ")` which is wrong.

All I can think of is to check for next line character as the end of the query as each query is separated by two empty lines. So tried these `if (line.contains(" ''')\n")` & `if (line.contains(" ''')\r\n")` but none of them work for me.

Kindly let me know of any other way to do this.

Note that I do not have the privilege to change the query file.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure why you using `contains` to locate the start, wouldn't `indexOf` be what you want to begin with? And following that you have the `lastIndexOf` function as well.

Answer (score 0):

I believe simple contains won't solve this problem.

You will have to use Pattern if you are looking to match `\n`.

```
String query = "spark.sql(''' SELECT .......\n" +
        "FROM..... \n" +
        "WHERE  xxx IN ('''+ Variable +''')\n" +
        "''')";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^spark.sql\\('''(.*)'''\\)$", Pattern.DOTALL);
System.out.println(pattern.matcher(query).find());
```

Output:

```
true
```

> `Pattern.DOTALL` tells Java to allow the dot to match newline characters, too.